# When to use X1 or X2 capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, ac, x-capacitor

I've a simple circuit where I need to detect AC voltage presence via a microcontroller (ESP32).

The ESP32 is a 3.3V device, and requires (worst case) 2.8V to consider a logical one on a GPIO.

I'm using a photocoupler (TLP290) for this. Such photocoupler requires at least 0.5mA to start conducting (the CTR for such a low diode current is only 70% typically).

On the AC side, I'm currently using two `1/4W` resistors in SMD. (See top circuit). For the configuration shown, I'm expecting `0.7mA` in the circuit (input is 230Vac at 50Hz), so the resistors will dissipate `~90mW` each. In case of overvoltage, with 280Vac, they'll dissipate `~130mW` each.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvda1P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think such power might cause issues (like local high temperature on the PCB) so I'm trying to replace the basic resitors by a more complex RC filter so that the impedance is close to what I want at 50Hz, but less power is dissipated in the resistors.

See the bottom circuit for an example implementation. In such circuit, the impedance of the RC filter is `~300kOhm` at `50Hz` so the same current flows in the circuit, but then the power dissipated in the resistors is now only `12mW`.

I understand I must use a X rated capacitor for this case (I'm not connected to ground in that case), but I don't understand which of X1 or X2 type I must use.

I'd like to avoid using film capacitors here, since they only exist in through hole version, and I'd like to use SMD capacitors here (15nF does exists in SMD in 2010 package).

*note:* I haven't found an optocoupler in the circuit drawing software on this site, so please consider the D1 or D2 diode as the 2 inputs diodes of the AC photocoupler.

Comment: Besides your worries about power dissipation (that I'll not address in this comment), you should be concerned about the reverse voltage in the optocoupler's diode, at the negative cycles of AC. You could use a 1N4007 diode reversed in parallel (be aware that the optocoupler will flash at 25 Hz), or you could use a full bridge rectifier before the optocoupler's LED.

Comment: The schematic here is wrong (I was not able to find a suitable symbol in this site's software). The optocoupler is a AC one, with two diodes in opposite direction (both emit light to trigger the phototransistor), so it's already accounting/dealing for/with reverse voltage.

Comment: You must add a series resistor, otherwise there is little to limit the current in case of power applied at the peak of the mains or in case of a transient on the mains.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this optocoupler. If it's an AC one, with two diodes, my point is addressed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, You mean before the RC filter ? The AC line is protected by a varistor (not shown in schematic) + 2 Y2 capacitor to the ground. Is that enough ?

Comment: Imagine you switch the input on at the peak of the 230V mains. 325 volts will suddenly appear across some combination of the capacitor ESR, the mains inductance, whatever resistance may be there, and the LED. The current will be hard to predict, but definitely above the absolute maximum rating of the LEDs.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when the capacitor is not charged, it appears like a huge resistor dubbed *insulating resistance* in the datasheet (which is something like 100MOhm or so). It's only when it's charged that the ESR starts to bother. If you apply 325V on the circuit initially, then it's like we have a 100MOhm in parallel to a 2MOhm (see bottom schematic), so it'll mainly be 2MOhm before hitting the diode in the photocoupler. The current in the LED will be 0.1mA (the current that flows in the resistor path, not the capacitor path), so it should be ok. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, The TLP290 supports up to 1A as input pulsed current (during 0.1ms), and up to 50mA in RMS current, so it would "burn" only if the resistance in the path is less than 6.5 kOhm. I don't get how that could happen, but I can put a 6.8kOhm in serie with the RC filter to prevent this, if this is what you meant.